# Dijkstra's algorithm in Java source and target

Tags: java, graph, dijkstra

I'm trying to use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path between two nodes in the graph.

what should I do to the following code to stop calculating when the shortest path between the source and the target is found?

```
public void calculate(Vertex source){
    // Algo:
    // 1. Take the unvisited node with minimum weight.
    // 2. Visit all its neighbours.
    // 3. Update the distances for all the neighbours (In the Priority Queue).
    // Repeat the process till all the connected nodes are visited.

    source.minDistance = 0;
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> queue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
    queue.add(source);

    while(!queue.isEmpty()){

        Vertex u = queue.poll();

        for(Edge neighbour:u.neighbours){
            Double newDist = u.minDistance+neighbour.weight;

            if(neighbour.target.minDistance>newDist){
                // Remove the node from the queue to update the distance value.
                queue.remove(neighbour.target);
                neighbour.target.minDistance = newDist;

                // Take the path visited till now and add the new node.s
                neighbour.target.path = new LinkedList<Vertex>(u.path);
                neighbour.target.path.add(u);

                //Reenter the node with new distance.
                queue.add(neighbour.target);                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> what should I do to the following code to stop calculating when the
>   shortest path between the source and the target is found

You can't "break" in the middle because you can't tell if there isn't a shorter path than the one you've already found until the algorithm finishes.